# Scroll buffer-window whilst Ex-log open

Tags: vimscript, error

From time to time I do a `source` of a script and N errors and warnings manifest. As the errors/warnings show it is impossible to scroll buffer/window. Cursor, at least in gvim is a bold white `x`.

The *log*  part of Vim is typically:

```
 Error detected while processing function Foo:
 line  16:
 E123: blah
 E456: blah
 line  38:
 E789 blah
 Press Enter or type a command to continue
```

My want is to be able to scroll the buffer, typically to investigate reported errors, *while* the errors are showing. (So I do not have to memorize it for each run …).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to scroll the buffer while the Ex-command output is displaying.

A workaround is to redirect the output to a new file, which you can then open in a split.

```
:redir > output.txt
:source script.vim
:redir END
:split output.txt
```

Alternatively, if it's a script you're writing yourself, you could investigate the Decho plugin, which provides debug commands that can log output to a variety of destinations. Decho is included with the standard installation of Vim (`:help Decho.vim`).

Comment: Trying out some solutions based on the commands. Yes; it is when writing own scripts, (or debugging others), typically by `:so %` or the like.

Answer (score 4):

Vim stores up to 20 error messages by default in its messages history. This list can be reviewed using the command `:messages`.

For further information check:

```
:help :messages
:help 'shortmess'
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to mention that in my answer! Upvoted.

Comment: Yes, I use the `:messages` command, but this also renders the main window *un-scrollable*. Another issue I have with it is that it stores 200 messages (running normal, not tiny Vim.) If one have typically 200 messages it is going to fill entire height of Vim + it usually yield 1NN+ messages before the ones I want. The whole process becomes somewhat cumbersome - especially on multiple errors. *But*; +1 as it is relevant.

Comment: In that case I think that the answer @Rich posted is what you are looking for. Maybe he could expand his answer to include mine such that it contains all relevant information?

Comment: @Vitor I don't think that's necessary. It's fine for different answers to contain different solutions for the same problem. If people don't like my answer I'm sure they'll read yours, and vice versa!